# Closure of point spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let, $T: \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$ defined as $T(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) = (\lambda_1x_1,\lambda_2x_2,\lambda_3x_3\dots)$. Show that the spectrum of the operator $T$ is the closure of the point spectrum.

I am not sure, how to proceed.

Kindly, help me out.
Thanks!

Comment: Please do not vandalise questions.  If you are unhappy with the closure of your question follow the advice given in the closure notice and improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer has been downvoted possibly because the question has been voted for closure.  In my defense I would like to state that OP did show some effort initially. Subsequently the effort has been deleted. I have mentioned one of OP's inequalities in my answer below, so I was justified in answering this question.

$Te_i=\lambda_ie_i$ so each $\lambda_i$ is an eigen value. The closure of $\{\lambda_i: i \geq 1\}$ is contained in the spectrum. If $\lambda$ is not in this closure then there exits $r>0$ such that $|\lambda -\lambda_i | \geq r$ for all $i$. Define $Sx=(\frac 1 {(\lambda_i-\lambda)} x_i)$. Verfy that $S$ is a bounded operator such that $(T-\lambda I)S=S(T-\lambda I)=I$. So $\lambda$ belongs to the resolvent of $T$.

In your inequality you can take $c=\inf |\lambda_i-\lambda|$.

Comment: @cabmetric Let $S$ be the closure of the set of eigen values. I have proved that $\lambda \notin S$ $\implies \lambda $ belongs to resolvent of $T$. Taking compelments this says that the spectrum  of $T$ is contained $S$. Since the revesre inclusion is also true it folows that the spectrum is eactly equal to  $S$, the closure of the set of eigen values.

Comment: aaha! I missed that. Thanks